# Vivado simulation waveform

Tags: simulation, xilinx, waveform, vivado

Simple question about vivado simulations.

Is it possible to continue waveform simulation in VIVADO, once you save it / close it and reopen it?

I could only reopen it but i was not able to rerun it once opened.

Answer (score 0):

Which command are using to save waveform? If you just save as *.vcd or similar format Vivado is not able to continue in simulation as the file does not contains all of the state of the simulation.